# Web Scraping - stock prices, quandl

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, web-scraping, quandl

I have a quick question. My code looks like below:

```
import quandl

names_of_company = ['KGHM','INDYKPOL','KRUK','KRUSZWICA']

for names in names_of_company:
    x = quandl.get('WSE/{names_of_company}', start_date='2018-11-26', 
    end_date='2018-11-29')
```

I am trying to get all the data in one output but I can't change the names of each company one after another. Do you have any ideas?

Thanks for help

Comment: did the answer below not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unless I'm missing something, looks like you should just be able to do a pretty basic `for` loop. it was the syntax that was was incorrect.

```
import quandl
import pandas as pd

names_of_company = ['KGHM','INDYKPOL','KRUK','KRUSZWICA']

results = pd.DataFrame()

for names in names_of_company:
    x = quandl.get('WSE/%s' %names, start_date='2018-11-26', 
    end_date='2018-11-29')
    x['company'] = names
    results = results.append(x).reset_index(drop=True)
```